# Zip Archive: Entry name problems

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I experienced two problems with the zip archive which I want to share here and ask for your experience as well:

1. Duplicate directories
   If I create two or more directories of the same name in the archive(below the root) the archive contains both directories (when looking in the Entries) but every ZIP-Application (also Windows) shows me only one directory. I did it like this:

   ```
   using (ZipArchive a = ZipFile.Open("D:\\zip.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Update))
   {
       ZipArchiveEntry e1 = a.CreateEntry("dir1/");
       ZipArchiveEntry e2 = a.CreateEntry("dir1/");

       foreach (var afile in a.Entries)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(afile.FullName);
       }
   }
   ```

The level itself doesn't matter, also if I go one level down ("dir1/dir2/") the same happens.

2. Missing entries
   By mistake I put a slash as the first character of a directory or filename. Both entries are visible also in the Entries property, but are also not visible on ZIP-applications (also Windows):

   ```
   using (ZipArchive a = ZipFile.Open("D:\\zip.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Update))
   {
       ZipArchiveEntry e1 = a.CreateEntry("/dir1");
       ZipArchiveEntry e2 = a.CreateEntry("/dir1.txt");

       foreach (var afile in a.Entries)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(afile.FullName);
       }
   }
   ```

Have any of you ever experienced this problem? Is it only a problem that ZIP can do it, but no application is able to display it, or is this a mistake that is not properly handled by the creation routines?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these behaviors are perfectly normal. They arise from your misunderstanding of how .zip archives work, and how `ZipArchive` in particular operates.

First, as I mentioned in my answer to your other `ZipArchive` question, there is not really any "directory" per se in a .zip archive. They exist only by virtue of entries created with the directory names in their names.

So if you add an entry named `dir1/dir2/test1.txt`, you get "directories" named `dir1` and `dir2`. If you delete that entry, those directories just disappear.

So when you think you are creating directories, you're really just creating new entries. And as the documentation says, you can create more than one entry with the same name. Of course, what will happen in this case depends on the tool you use to open the archive. Many (as you've found) will show you only the first item.

The solution is to not try to create directories. That doesn't work. Just write entries with the directory paths you want. The directories are "created" implicitly by virtue of actual items being named as being in those directories.

As far as the leading `/` character goes, by specification all file paths in a .zip archive should be "relative", that is they should not include a leading `/` character. [The MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158346(v=vs.110).aspx) even calls this out specifically:

> The entryName string should reflect the relative path of the entry you want to create within the zip archive. There is no restriction on the string you provide. However, if it is not formatted as a relative path, the entry is created, but you may get an exception when you extract the contents of the zip archive.

It seems in your case, no exception occurs, but you simply don't have access to the archive entry when the archive is opened in other tools. The solution is, "don't do that".

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I wrote a wrapper around this, but before I finalize my wrapper I needed some information. Now I got this information and I can prevent the misuse in my wrapper.